# Built kernel for 5.10.0-rc5 but when I do insmod, it complains it's for 5.4.21

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I used to build my kernel module against 5.4.21 but today I built it against 5.10.0-rc5.
But when I do insmod after linux 5.10.0-rc5 is booted in a virtual machine, it complains like this.

```
/test1 # insmod axpu_ldd_kc.ko
[ 3331.286276] axpu_ldd_kc: version magic '5.4.21 SMP preempt mod_unload aarch64' should be '5.10.0-rc5 SMP preempt mod_unload aarch64'
insmod: can't insert 'axpu_ldd_kc.ko': invalid module format
```

So somewhere the 5.4.21 setting is used for the driver. My Makefile for the module build for 5.10.0-rc5 is like this.

```
export CROSS_COMPILE:=aarch64-none-linux-gnu-
export ARCH:=arm64
obj-m += axpu_ldd_kc.o

# test for ubuntu
export KDIR:=/home/ckim/ProjX/LinuxDevDrv/kernel-release-RD-INFRA-2020.11.30
ccflags-y:=-I/home/ckim/ProjX/QEMU/qemu-6.2.0/hw/misc
ccflags-y+=-I../../../../../axpusim/axpu
ccflags-y+=-I$(PWD)

all:
    make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

What can be wrong? (the /home/ckim/ProjX/LinuxDevDrv/kernel-release-RD-INFRA-2020.11.30 directory is 5.10.0-rc5)

**SOLVED :**
thanks for the comments. I found what was wrong. In the VM, I used tftp to get the driver and application. To get the driver I did tftp -g -r axpu_ldd_kc.ko 129.254.32.30. And I thought my tftp server directory of my machine (129.254.32.30) is /opt/tftp and placed the driver and app there. But it turns out my tftp server directory was /srv/tftp (ubuntu 20.04, set in /etc/default/tftpd-hpa). So I was using old driver file in /srv/tftp. :) I have forgot /srv/tftp is the new server directory.

Comment: are you installing to the correct directory?

Comment: That is weird, is the kernel in the KDIR folder a clean build? Try rebuilding it after a `make distclean` just to be sure. Also, are you sure you are copying the final `.ko` file in the VM correctly? Check the files with `sha1sum` and `modinfo` on both machines and see if the output matches. And I am pretty sure you don't need to type `export VAR:=...`, just `VAR:=...` should be ok, but I admit I don't know the difference between the two honestly (I just know I've always used the version without `export`).

Comment: Oh and is the `PWD` env var set correctly when you run this Makefile? You are probably safer adding `PWD:=$(shell pwd)` at the top of the file just to be sure. If all the stuff I am talking about is OK (or applying my suggestions doesn't change the result) then I'm kind of out of ideas...

Comment: thanks for the comments. I found what was wrong. In the VM, I used tftp to get the driver and application. To get the driver I did `tftp -g -r axpu_ldd_kc.ko 129.254.32.30`. And I thought my tftp server directory of my machine (129.254.32.30) is /opt/tftp and placed the driver and app there. But it turns out my tftp server directory was /srv/tftp (ubuntu 20.04, set in /etc/default/tftpd-hpa). So I was using old driver file in /srv/tftp. :) I have forgot /srv/tftp is the new server directory.

Comment: Then I think we can close this question as a typo.

Comment: @stark Hi, how can I close my question? I voted to close it. but I'm curious if the original poster can just close it.

Comment: It needs 1 more vote from somebody to close.  Don't worry about it.